# python osmnx geocode_to_gdf Nominatim not working while web-based openstreetmaps does

Tags: python, geocoding, osmnx, nominatim

I am trying to geocode a list of objects (mostly road names) to their coordinates from python wth `osmnx.geocode_to_gdf`.
The problem is that I often  get returned with the following error message (example of query *"Jln Kuang, Singapore"*):

```
ValueError: Nominatim could not geocode query "Jln Kuang, Singapore" to polygonal boundaries
```

While using the same exact query in the web version of Open Street Map (https://www.openstreetmap.org/)  I do get the correct result, in this case pointing me to the right road.

Answer (score 2):

Without passing **which_result** `geocode_to_gdf()` will look for a polygon.  In this case it is a *way* (road) hence it's a line string

```
import osmnx as ox

ox.geocode_to_gdf("Jln Kuang, Singapore", which_result=1)
```

Comment: Yes, this solves it. Thanks a lot!